# how to calculate the value of negative root

Tags: geometry, math-software

Below I am pasting equations of [superquadrics](https://superquadrics.com/):
[image]

for $\varepsilon_1 = 0.5$ and $\varepsilon_2 = 0.5$ some values are not valid (e.g. $\cos(\pi)^{0.5}$).

I would appreciate if anyone explained how to correctly calculate $x, y$, and $z$ values for arbitrary $\eta, \omega$, and $\varepsilon$.

I tried to use the following function to calculate the distance between the body surface and point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ but in case of $\varepsilon = 0.5$, I get an error:

```
def get_distance(x, x0, y0, z0, alpha1, alpha2, alpha3, epsilon1, epsilon2):
    return np.sqrt((x0 - alpha1*np.cos(x[0])**epsilon1*np.cos(x[1])**epsilon2)**2 + (y0 - alpha2*np.cos(x[1])**epsilon1*np.sin(x[1])**epsilon2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take the absolute values of the trig functions, $\cos \eta, \sin \eta, \cos \omega, \sin \omega$ before raising them to powers, then carry the signs over.  Non-integer powers of negative numbers are not well defined.

Comment: I rewrote the trigonometric functions as follows: cos(alpha)^n -> sign(cos(alpha))*(abs(cos(alpha))^n. Wasn’t sure if this way is correct.

Comment: That works.  Alternately you can just compute the first octant, where all the trig functions are positive, then take all eight sign combinations on each point.